# Responsive Relative Element Resizing + Responsive Text Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, layout

I ran into 2 problems while designing a image-based drop-down menu :

1. No matter how long I try I can NOT get a `flex`ed element within a container to remain the same height as the adjacent element. [If you look at my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rbafhtc/2/), each slideout content that is revealed by hover,should be the same height as the icons.]
2. I can't get text over each image- I believe it is because the menu resizes itself based on devices width - which I cannot give up. All sources I've seen are based off of `position:absolute`, which I have not been able to get to work. [Specifically, there should be text on top of each image, labeling them.]

Comment for clarifications, if needed.

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rbafhtc/2/)  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Exosylver, little responses. Still need help with this?

Comment: @RenevanderLende Yes!!

Comment: Question: do you want the `<header>` and `<footer>`  visible at all times, or can there be more that four images and is the currently scrolling behaviour required?

Comment: @RenevanderLende I do want the ```<header>``` to be seen on first load, along with the menu (4 images). The ```<footer>``` is supposed to be stickied to the bottom, so that on mobile, the whole screen is utilized (although there wouldn't be scrolling in that case, because the footer is already sinking lower than it needs to). So, There IS scrolling, just only the height of the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity and code recycling the CSS has been split into four main sections:

- Globals, page defaults and overrides of standard HTML/CSS values
- Mechanism, Flexbox Layout settings and element sizing/actions
- Eye-candy generics, spacing, fonts, borders
- Eye-candy theming, anything color related using custom attribute `[theme="gr-blue"]`. Can be easily extended with other themes.

**Flexbox Layout**

For the left and right alignment of the `.slideout-content` you can simply use the `row-reverse` direction and `justify-content: flex-end` for an *odd* `.menu-item` and the default `row` direction for an *even* `.menu-item`

**Image text overlay**

Uses the standard `position: relative` and `absolute` parent/child element construction. The child `content` is filled with *overlay text* obtained from `data-overlay` custom attribute.

**Remarks**

- The code is heavily commented and shows a few alternative uses for Flexbox Layout.
- Removed `filter: brightness(1.2)` as IE11 cannot handle this, will need some alternative.
- I have slightly changed the color opacity of `.slideout-content` to show some hover effects.
- Where applicable I added viewport depended sizes.
- Removed all uses of child `margin` and moved spacing to parent `padding` where applicable. This is especially important when using relative sizes ('%') combined with `box-sizing: border-box`, as `margin` increases the size of a child beyond 100%.
- Don't use `flex: 1` to allow elements to grow, use `flex-grow: 1` instead for use with IE11.
- Change `dir="ltr"` in `<body>` to `dir="rtl"` to test document reading order.

**Tested** to work with Chrome/Edge, Firefox and IE11 at a minimum size of 320x480px, without the need for scrolling.

**UPDATE 1** I forgot to mention that I removed original `footer {...height: 5vh...}` which is not high enough for its content and will therefore overflow creating a white bar below the footer.

If you don't want a footer (or any parent element for that matter) to overflow, its `height` has to be at least greater/equal in height to its child(ren) (calculate `line-height + padding + border + margin` => whether to add `padding + border` depends on `box-sizing`).

**UPDATE 2** To position overlay `.slideout::after` 3/4 from top and center in parent use: `.slideout::after { top: 75%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }`, I modified the CSS accordingly. Check out [w3schools: CSS Layout - Horizontal & Vertical Align](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) for more info on positioning.

**SNIPPET**

```css
/***********/
/* GLOBALS */
/***********/
html,body           { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }

html                { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box }
*, *:before, *:after{ -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; box-sizing: inherit }

/* remove/override default element default */
html                { -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% }
body                { margin: 0 }
ul,li               { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
a                   { text-decoration: none; color: inherit }
p                   { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 }

/* for debugging (put in <body>) */
[outlines="1"] *    { outline: 1px dashed }

/*************/
/* MECHANISM */
/*************/

/******************/
/* Flexbox Layout */
/******************/

/* FBL EITHER (specific) */
/*.wrapper, .touch-menu, .menu-item,
.menu-item *                { display: flex }/**/

/* FBL OR (generic, if you want to insert elements on-the-fly without classes) */
div, ul, li, a, img         { display: flex }/**/

/* .wrapper is an FBL column of three main rows, pushed apart */
.wrapper                    { flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between }

/* .touch-menu fills available space and is a row that wraps its kids */
.touch-menu                 { flex-grow: 1; flex-flow: row wrap }

/* 
   Because .menu-item width is 50% there will always be only two in a row,
   simply reverse FBL for first in a row...
*/
.menu-item:nth-child(odd)   { flex-direction: row-reverse } /* reverse row logic */
.menu-item:nth-child(odd)>* { justify-content: flex-end   } /* ditto */

.slideout-content           { flex-grow: 1 }           /* grow to fill parent */
.slideout-content ul        { flex-direction: column } /* a column of several rows */

.touch-menu,.slideout-content *, /* center all content rows/columns */
.header>*,.footer>*         { justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: center }
.footer>*                   { justify-content: flex-end } /* right align footer rows */

/**********/
/* Action */
/**********/
.slideout-content       { display: none } /* hide, change to 'flex' to verify positioning */

.slideout:hover+.slideout-content,
.slideout-content:hover { display: flex } /* show on hover */

/**********/
/* Sizing */
/**********/
.wrapper                { width: 100%; height: 100% }
.touch-menu             { padding: 0 5% }
/* modify 5% to required need, forces size of entire .menu-item */

.menu-item              { width: 50% } /* of .touch-menu */
.slideout               { width: 50%; position: relative } /* of .menu-item  */
.slideout::after        { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0 }

/* UPDATE 2 */
.slideout::after        { top: 75%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }


/* redundant, but > 50% will animate .slideout on hover */
.slideout-content       { width: 50% } /* otherwise: remove */

/* fill parent */
.header>*, .footer>*,
.slideout img           { width: 100% }
.slideout-content *     { width: 100%; height: 100% } /* modify to your needs */

/**********************/
/* EYE-CANDY generics */
/**********************/
.header                 { border-bottom-style: inset }
.header .headline       { padding: 0.67em 0; font-size: 2.6vw; font-weight: bold }
.touch-menu .menu-item  { padding: 1vh }

.slideout               { cursor: pointer }
.slideout::after        { content: attr(data-overlay); font-size: .75vw; padding: .25vw }

.slideout-content       { font-size: 1.5vw; padding: .25vw; box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) }
.slideout-content ul *  { border-radius: 0.5vw } 
.slideout-content li    { padding: .125vw }
.slideout-content a     { border: thin inset }

.footer                 { padding: 2.65vmin .75vw; font-size: .75vw; border-top: outset }

/* ONLY required when 'FBL EITHER' used */
.header                 { text-align: center }
.footer                 { text-align: right  }

/*********************/
/* EYE-CANDY theming */
/*********************/
body { font-family: "Lato", sans-serif }

body[theme="gr-blue"] {
    color: GoldenRod; 
    /*
        Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient:
        https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#c7d7dd+0,a7cfdf+16,5085a0+57,23538a+100
    */
    background-color: rgb(199,215,221); /* Old browsers */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(199,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(167,207,223,1) 16%, rgba(80,133,160,1) 57%, rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(199,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(167,207,223,1) 16%, rgba(80,133,160,1) 57%, rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background-image:   linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(199,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(167,207,223,1) 16%, rgba(80,133,160,1) 57%, rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c7d7dd', endColorstr='#23538a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

[theme="gr-blue"] .header { color: AliceBlue; background-color: #605e5e; border-bottom-color: #888888 }
[theme="gr-blue"] .footer { background-color:#605e5e; border-color: GoldenRod }

[theme="gr-blue"] .slideout::after           { color: AliceBlue; background-color: rgba(115,110,111,.6) }
[theme="gr-blue"] .slideout-content          { background-color: rgba(115,110,111,.6) } /* #736e6f */
[theme="gr-blue"] .slideout-content a        { border-color: #888585 }
[theme="gr-blue"] .slideout-content li:hover { background-color: rgba(115,110,111,.6) }
```

```html
<body theme="gr-blue" dir="ltr" outlines="0">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headline">Links of Links</div>
    </div>

    <div class="touch-menu">
        <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="slideout" data-overlay="overlay 1">
                <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
            </div>
            <div class="slideout-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">scaleLink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">scaleLink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">scaleLink 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="slideout" data-overlay="overlay 2">
                <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
            </div>
            <div class="slideout-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">bookLink 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="slideout" data-overlay="overlay 3">
                <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
            </div>
            <div class="slideout-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ugavelLink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ugavelLink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ugavelLink 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ugavelLink 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="slideout" data-overlay="overlay 4">
                <img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
            </div>
            <div class="slideout-content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">lgavelLink 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">lgavelLink 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">lgavelLink 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div>
            Powered by <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=emb_logo" target="_blank">Barack Obama</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Just one thing: there is a white bar at the bottom of the page, I need the background to stretch all the way from header to footer.

Comment: Did you change the height of the `<footer>` to `5vh` again? Because `5vh` is not high enough for its content and will make it overflow, hence the white bar below (due to `<p>` height and margin). Calculate: parent height has to be >= child(ren) `line-height` + `padding` + `margin`. I actually forgot to mention why I removed `footer.height`, sorry.

Comment: I actually think the problem was that the gradient background abruptly cuts off, which made me think it was a problem with the footer heights.

Comment: My posted version (tested it again) does not show the white bar below the footer, only during  resizing which is totally acceptable (Firefox slight white, Chrome/Edge blank line at he bottom of the screen, depends on browser rendering graphics, I guess).  However, the remark about the footer height of `5vh` still is true, I noticed this running your version the first time. Should the gradient give you any trouble, try various options of its`background-attachment` and `background-size`.

Comment: One more thing: How can I center the overlays to the 3/4to the top, center- when the all the overlay texts are different sizes?

Comment: Much obliged! You could use `.slideout::after { top: 75%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }` to position within parent and center it at that position (`top: 50%` would be dead center, check [w3schools: CSS Layout - Horizontal & Vertical Align](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) for some more fun stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have the `menu-top` display as `flex` in order for its contents to stretch. For the overlay on the image the `position: absolute` rule is correct but it would need one of the positioning rules `top right bottom left` to be declared as well, and its parent to have `relative` position.
I have created a flexbox-based snippet based on what you described. Note that I didn't use any columns, instead the children are wrapping on 50% and I use `:nth-child(odd)` to select the odd children and `order: 1` or `order: 2` rules accordingly to display the menu left or right.
Also note that I used a `.page__wrap` class on a div to wrap the whole page, header, main and footer in order to flex them so the footer is always at the bottom even if there is no scrolling.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page__wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em 0;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  background-color: gold;
  padding: 1em 0;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

.slideouts__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 65rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slideout {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.slideout:nth-child(odd) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.slideout__avatar {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.slideout__avatar--image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

.slideout__avatar--overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00000095;
  color: white;
  transition: .2s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slideout:nth-child(odd) .slideout__avatar {
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.slideout__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.slideout__menu--items {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  flex: 1;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #736E6F;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 1%;
}

.slideout__menu--item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: thin inset #888585;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.slideout__menu--item:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.slideout__menu--item--anchor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
    color: goldenrod;
}

.slideout__avatar:hover + .slideout__menu .slideout__menu--items {
  display: flex;
}

.slideout__avatar:hover .slideout__avatar--overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slideout__menu--items:hover {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page__wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="header__container">
      <h2>links of links</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="slideouts__container">
    <div class="slideouts__wrapper">
      <div class="slideout">
        <div class="slideout__avatar">
          <img class="slideout__avatar--image" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
          <div class="slideout__avatar--overlay">
            <p>the overlay</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideout__menu">
          <ul class="slideout__menu--items">
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slideout">
        <div class="slideout__avatar">
          <img class="slideout__avatar--image" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
          <div class="slideout__avatar--overlay">
            <p>the overlay</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideout__menu">
          <ul class="slideout__menu--items">
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slideout">
        <div class="slideout__avatar">
          <img class="slideout__avatar--image" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
          <div class="slideout__avatar--overlay">
            <p>the overlay</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideout__menu">
          <ul class="slideout__menu--items">
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slideout">
        <div class="slideout__avatar">
          <img class="slideout__avatar--image" src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/105/thumb-105223.jpg" alt="scale">
          <div class="slideout__avatar--overlay">
            <p>the overlay</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideout__menu">
          <ul class="slideout__menu--items">
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li class="slideout__menu--item"><a class="slideout__menu--item--anchor" href="#">link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer__container">
      <p>footer text</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very close to what I wanted, but there are just 2 things: The overlay should always be visible. The 4 boxes (menu) needs to resize with the width of the page, so on phones the slideouts are visible.

Comment: That is fairly easy, modifying the `flex` rule to `0 1 auto` on the `.slideout__avatar` and a `width: 100%` rule to the image `.slideout__avatar--image` you are basically telling the container to shrink accordingly to the viewport, although I would like to stress that you would neet to add some restrictions/breakpoint for readability/accessibility.
For the overlay you just remove the `opacity: 0` rule and change `width` and `height` to your liking. I updated the snippet with the changes so you can see it in action.